# Update array of dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have array of dictionaries, and I want to update values in the dictionary by key, this keys are in another array. How can update it simply?

```
Dictionary<string, int>[] arr_dict = new Dictionary<string,int> [lines.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    arr_dict[i] = new Dictionary<string, int>(init_dict);
}
```

This is defining the array of dictionaries by keys that i already know, the initial value of each key is `0`.

Now my problem is how to approach  this values and update them.

Comment: How exactly do you want to update the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Add(Dictionary<string, int> arr_dict, int index, string key)
{
    arr_dict[index][key] = arr_dict[index][key] + 1;
}

public void Update(Dictionary<string, int> arr_dict, int index, string key, int value)
{
    arr_dict[index][key] = value;
}
```

Comment: This i know , but like i said before , my keys is in another big array over then 100 different keys , i dont know how to put the keys in the arr_dict[key] , it dosent works

Comment: My mistake, you need to use an integer to retrieve the dictionary. Putting a key in can be done with the same code as updating the value of a key.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple access the `i`-th dictionary with:

```
arr_dict[i]
```

which is a [`Dictionary<String,int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This means you can call any method defined for `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` on them to update, retrieve and add data.

For instance:

```
arr_dict[0].Add("foo",5);  //Add foo -> 5 into the first dictionary
arr_dict[2].Add("bar",42); //Add bar -> 42 into the third one

int val = arr_dict[2]["bar"]; //Obtain the value associated with "bar" from the second dictionary
//etc...
```

See the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an exhaustive and well documented list of methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private Dictionary<string,int> _dictn = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    public void Add_Update_ToDictn(string key, int id)
    {
        if (_dictn.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _dictn[key] = id;
        }
        else
        {
            _dictn.Add(key, id);
        }           
    }
```

Loop the other source dictionary and pass the key and value to this method. This will update the existing value and if not it will insert.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
      Add_Update_ToDictn(i,init_dict[i]);
   }
```